# How to use a sum type as a key in map when using Aeson?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I wanted to encode a simple "map" in JSON:

```
{ "CS": "Ahoj"
, "EN": "Hello"
}
```

My attempt:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH (deriveJSON)
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as M
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Hashable (Hashable)

data Language
  = CS
  | EN
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, Hashable)

deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Language

newtype TranslatedText =
  TranslatedText (M.HashMap Language Text)
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

deriveJSON defaultOptions ''TranslatedText
```

I am getting:

```
/xxx/src/Data.hs:80:1: error:
    • No instance for (FromJSONKey Language)
        arising from a use of ‘parseJSON’
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘parseJSON arg_apgG’
      In the expression: (TranslatedText <$> parseJSON arg_apgG)
      In a case alternative:
          arg_apgG -> (TranslatedText <$> parseJSON arg_apgG)
   |
80 | deriveJSON defaultOptions ''TranslatedText
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/xxx/src/Data.hs:80:1: error:
    • No instance for (ToJSONKey Language)
        arising from a use of ‘toJSON’
    • In the expression: toJSON arg1_apfY
      In a case alternative: TranslatedText arg1_apfY -> toJSON arg1_apfY
      In the expression:
        case value_apdm of { TranslatedText arg1_apfY -> toJSON arg1_apfY }
   |
80 | deriveJSON defaultOptions ''TranslatedText
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/xxx/src/Data.hs:80:1: error:
    • No instance for (ToJSONKey Language)
        arising from a use of ‘toEncoding’
    • In the expression: toEncoding arg1_apgk
      In a case alternative:
          TranslatedText arg1_apgk -> toEncoding arg1_apgk
      In the expression:
        case value_apg9 of {
          TranslatedText arg1_apgk -> toEncoding arg1_apgk }
   |
80 | deriveJSON defaultOptions ''TranslatedText
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried writing `FromJSONKey` and `ToJSONKey` instances using `readMaybe` and `show`, but I don't know how one should construct a `Parser`? Or is there some better, more automatic way? After all the sum type can easily be converted from/to `Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what a typical instance looks like, using `Show` and `Read` (a deriving clause for `Read` needs to be added to `Language`):

```
-- Additional imports
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

instance ToJSONKey Language where
  toJSONKey = toJSONKeyText (T.pack . show)

instance FromJSONKey Language where
  fromJSONKey = FromJSONKeyTextParser $ \t -> case readMaybe (T.unpack t) of
    Just k -> pure k
    Nothing -> fail ("Invalid key: " ++ show t)
```

There should be a shorter way, I've submitted a proposal to add generic implementations: https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/710

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely :). Edit: For others - `text` comes from `Data.Aeson.Encoding`.